# create array of types in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to create an array of types in dart?

I know there is a way to create a `List<Type>` and have any type in the list. But does Dart allows us to be more specific about the type superclass? I want to create a List of subclasses of a class called `Component`.

```dart
abstract class Component {}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want a `List` of *instances* of different `Component`-derived classes, use `List<Component>`.  If you want a `List` of `Component` *types* (e.g. `[Component, FooComponent, BarComponent]`), then you would need to use `List<Type>`, and there is no way to restrict it to allow only some `Type`s but not others.

Comment: Cool. I was not sure about that. Do you want to make a reply so I can accept it?